# Is there a better way to split up this Pinia action?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuex, pinia

I'm planning to split my Pinia actions into their own files, the following works but it doesn't feel too elegant. Is there a better way to declare the `signOut` method in actions?

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

const signOut = ($this, payload) => {
  console.log($this.username, payload); // "test-account", true
};

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", {
  state: () => ({
    username: "test-account",
  }),
  getters: {
    ...
  },
  actions: {
    signOut(payload) { // <-- is there a better way to write this part?
      signOut(this, payload); // <--
    },
  },
});

// in component elsewhere: signOut(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should immediately switch to the alternative syntax for defining stores. Check out the docs here: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores

Basically you'd write it like this

```
import { signOut } from "my-signout-service"

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", () => {
  const username = ref("test-account");

  const logout = async (payload) => {
    //do your sign out stuff
    await signOut(username.value, payload)
    username.value = null
  }

  return {
    username,
    logout
  }

});
```

This should look familiar to you if you're familiar with writing normal composable functions.
My favorite part about using this syntax? You don't have to reference `this` anymore. All your variables are defined and used normally within the scope of the function.

Comment: That looks to be a way easier solution, handling `this` is a pain. How would you go about declaring `signOut` if it's imported from an external file?

Comment: Is it necessary to call from within the pinia store? I'll edit my post with my idea

Comment: I'm looking to have `signOut` outside of the store, and import it.

Comment: I edited the post with an example of something you might need to do. I would just import and use the function 'normally'

Comment: That looks good, but is it possible to call the `signOut` directly and still have access to the state variables? (eg I would like to call `user.value = null` from inside the `signOut` method in the external file).

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do that. Keep things separated so that the 'context' at each level is very clear. Your signOut method should do 1 thing.... sign them out. Clearing the user state should happen outside at the level that maintains the user state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249339/discussion-between-robokozo-and-jcraine).